# Django:Find no of days between 2 dates and compare with sysdate and return if it matches

Tags: python, django

I want to know who is on leave today based on end_date and start_date which are DatetimeField by comparing  values between end_date and start_date with sysdate and returning if it matches with sysdate.

```
models.py
class leave(models.Model): 
employee = models.ForeignKey(employees, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
start_date = models.DateField()
end_date = models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a queryset of `leave` instances:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
leave.objects.filter(start_date__lt=today, end_date__gt=today)
```

Or use `__lte` and `__gte` if you want to include the boundaries, EG including `leave` instances that started today.

If you want employees, follow the foreign key:

```
employees.objects.filter(leave__set_date__lt=today, leave__end_date__gt=today)
```

If you don't have anything enforcing that there can't be overlapping `leave` instances for the sample employee, add `.distinct()` to the `employees` queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `start_date`, `end_date` and `today` are all `date` objects, you can check if someone is on leave this way: `today >= start_date and today <= end_date`.